# Issue starting LXD containers

Tags: lxc, arm, lxd

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and kernel Linux odroid 3.10.96-82.  My hardware is an ODROID-XU4 ARM based SBC with the Exynos5244 CPU.  I am having an issue getting LXD containers to start on this system but cannot figure out what I'm missing.  Here is the log file containing the errors I am seeing.  I am able to run containers via LXC without a problem.  Has anyone run into this before or know what I'm doing wrong or missing?  Thanks,

```
odroid@odroid:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:14.04/armhf
Creating annectent-melony
Retrieving image: 100%
Starting annectent-melony
error: Error calling 'lxd forkstart annectent-melony /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/annectent-melony/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'
Try `lxc info --show-log annectent-melony` for more info
odroid@odroid:~$ lxc list
+------------------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
|       NAME       |  STATE  | IPV4 | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+------------------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| annectent-melony | STOPPED |      |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+------------------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
odroid@odroid:~$ lxc delete annectent-melony
odroid@odroid:~$ lxc info --show-log annectent-melony
error: not found
odroid@odroid:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:14.04 elk01
Creating elk01
Starting elk01
error: Error calling 'lxd forkstart elk01 /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/elk01/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'
Try `lxc info --show-log elk01` for more info
odroid@odroid:~$ lxc info --show-log elk01
Name: elk01
Architecture: armv7l
Created: 2016/04/15 17:18 UTC
Status: Stopped
Type: persistent
Profiles: default

Log:

            lxc 20160415171819.134 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171819.134 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171848.376 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171848.377 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171848.463 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 3
            lxc 20160415171848.463 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 9
            lxc 20160415171848.472 INFO     lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:do_lxcapi_start:797 - Attempting to set proc title to [lxc monitor] /var/lib/lxd/containers elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.472 INFO     lxc_utils - utils.c:setproctitle:1460 - setting cmdline failed - Invalid argument
            lxc 20160415171848.474 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 9
            lxc 20160415171848.474 INFO     lxc_lsm - lsm/lsm.c:lsm_init:48 - LSM security driver nop
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .reject_force_umount  # comment this to allow umount -f;  not recommended.
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:436 - Adding native rule for reject_force_umount action 0
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:do_resolve_add_rule:216 - Setting seccomp rule to reject force umounts

            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .[all].
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .kexec_load errno 1.
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:436 - Adding native rule for kexec_load action 327681
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .open_by_handle_at errno 1.
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:436 - Adding native rule for open_by_handle_at action 327681
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .init_module errno 1.
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:436 - Adding native rule for init_module action 327681
            lxc 20160415171848.475 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .finit_module errno 1.
            lxc 20160415171848.476 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:436 - Adding native rule for finit_module action 327681
            lxc 20160415171848.476 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .delete_module errno 1.
            lxc 20160415171848.476 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:436 - Adding native rule for delete_module action 327681
            lxc 20160415171848.476 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/bin/lxd callhook /var/lib/lxd 9 start' for container 'elk01', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160415171848.478 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 3
            lxc 20160415171848.478 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 9
            lxc 20160415171848.487 INFO     lxc_monitor - monitor.c:lxc_monitor_sock_name:178 - using monitor sock name lxc/d78a9d7e97b4b375//var/lib/lxd/containers
            lxc 20160415171848.665 DEBUG    lxc_start - start.c:setup_signal_fd:289 - sigchild handler set
            lxc 20160415171848.668 DEBUG    lxc_console - console.c:lxc_console_peer_default:473 - no console peer
            lxc 20160415171848.668 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_init:488 - 'elk01' is initialized
            lxc 20160415171848.715 DEBUG    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1302 - Not dropping cap_sys_boot or watching utmp
            lxc 20160415171848.716 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:resolve_clone_flags:999 - Cloning a new user namespace
            lxc 20160415171848.747 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:instantiate_veth:2613 - instantiated veth 'vethFR9VUL/vethAMBU09', index is '11'
            lxc 20160415171848.748 INFO     lxc_cgroup - cgroup.c:cgroup_init:68 - cgroup driver cgroupfs-ng initing for elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.836 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_assign_network:3047 - move 'eth0' to '3870'
            lxc 20160415171848.865 NOTICE   lxc_start - start.c:do_start:763 - switching to gid/uid 0/0 in new user namespace
            lxc 20160415171848.866 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_rootfs:1215 - mounted '/var/lib/lxd/containers/elk01/rootfs' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc'
            lxc 20160415171848.866 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_utsname:843 - 'elk01' hostname has been setup
            lxc 20160415171848.906 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_hw_addr:2144 - mac address '00:16:3e:66:5e:2a' on 'eth0' has been setup
            lxc 20160415171848.907 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_netdev:2371 - 'eth0' has been setup
            lxc 20160415171848.907 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_network:2392 - network has been setup
            lxc 20160415171848.907 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_autodev:1072 - Mounting container /dev
            lxc 20160415171848.907 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_autodev:1095 - Mounted tmpfs onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev
            lxc 20160415171848.908 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_autodev:1113 - Mounted container /dev
            lxc 20160415171848.909 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1657 - remounting /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc on /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc to respect bind or remount options
            lxc 20160415171848.909 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1672 - (at remount) flags for /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc was 4096, required extra flags are 0
            lxc 20160415171848.909 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1681 - mountflags already was 20480, skipping remount
            lxc 20160415171848.909 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1707 - mounted '/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc', type 'none'
            lxc 20160415171848.909 ERROR    lxc_utils - utils.c:mkdir_p:253 - No such file or directory - failed to create directory '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/firmware/efi/'
            lxc 20160415171848.910 WARN     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry_create_dir_file:1755 - Failed to create mount target '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/firmware/efi/efivars'
            lxc 20160415171848.910 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1657 - remounting /sys/fs/fuse/connections on /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/fuse/connections to respect bind or remount options
            lxc 20160415171848.910 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1672 - (at remount) flags for /sys/fs/fuse/connections was 4096, required extra flags are 0
            lxc 20160415171848.910 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1681 - mountflags already was 20480, skipping remount
            lxc 20160415171848.910 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1707 - mounted '/sys/fs/fuse/connections' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/fuse/connections', type 'none'
            lxc 20160415171848.910 ERROR    lxc_utils - utils.c:mkdir_p:253 - No such file or directory - failed to create directory '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/pstore'
            lxc 20160415171848.911 WARN     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry_create_dir_file:1755 - Failed to create mount target '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/pstore'
            lxc 20160415171848.911 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1657 - remounting /sys/kernel/debug on /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/kernel/debug to respect bind or remount options
            lxc 20160415171848.911 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1672 - (at remount) flags for /sys/kernel/debug was 4096, required extra flags are 0
            lxc 20160415171848.911 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1681 - mountflags already was 20480, skipping remount
            lxc 20160415171848.911 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1707 - mounted '/sys/kernel/debug' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/kernel/debug', type 'none'
            lxc 20160415171848.911 ERROR    lxc_utils - utils.c:mkdir_p:253 - No such file or directory - failed to create directory '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/kernel/security'
            lxc 20160415171848.911 WARN     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry_create_dir_file:1755 - Failed to create mount target '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/kernel/security'
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1657 - remounting /dev/mqueue on /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev/mqueue to respect bind or remount options
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1672 - (at remount) flags for /dev/mqueue was 4096, required extra flags are 0
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1681 - mountflags already was 20480, skipping remount
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1707 - mounted '/dev/mqueue' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev/mqueue', type 'none'
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1657 - remounting /var/lib/lxd/devlxd on /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev/lxd to respect bind or remount options
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1672 - (at remount) flags for /var/lib/lxd/devlxd was 4096, required extra flags are 0
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1681 - mountflags already was 4096, skipping remount
            lxc 20160415171848.912 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1707 - mounted '/var/lib/lxd/devlxd' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev/lxd', type 'none'
            lxc 20160415171848.913 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1657 - remounting /var/lib/lxd/shmounts/elk01 on /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev/.lxd-mounts to respect bind or remount options
            lxc 20160415171848.913 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1672 - (at remount) flags for /var/lib/lxd/shmounts/elk01 was 4096, required extra flags are 0
            lxc 20160415171848.913 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1681 - mountflags already was 4096, skipping remount
            lxc 20160415171848.913 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1707 - mounted '/var/lib/lxd/shmounts/elk01' on '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/dev/.lxd-mounts', type 'none'
            lxc 20160415171848.913 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_file_entries:1926 - mount points have been setup
            lxc 20160415171848.914 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.914 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.914 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.915 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/debug read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.915 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/debug//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/debug//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.915 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/debug//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.916 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.916 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.916 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.916 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.916 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.917 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.917 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/memory read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.917 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/memory//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/memory//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.917 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/memory//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.918 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.918 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.918 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.918 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.918 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.919 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/freezer//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.919 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.919 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.919 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.920 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1292 - Remounted /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/devices read-only
            lxc 20160415171848.920 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1298 - Mounting /sys/fs/cgroup/devices//lxc/elk01 onto /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/devices//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.921 INFO     lxc_cgfsng - cgfsng.c:do_secondstage_mounts_if_needed:1306 - Completed second stage cgroup automounts for /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc/sys/fs/cgroup/devices//lxc/elk01
            lxc 20160415171848.921 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/share/lxcfs/lxc.mount.hook' for container 'elk01', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160415171849.551 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:fill_autodev:1141 - Creating initial consoles under container /dev
            lxc 20160415171849.551 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:fill_autodev:1152 - Populating container /dev
            lxc 20160415171849.552 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:fill_autodev:1189 - Populated container /dev
            lxc 20160415171849.553 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_dev_console:1437 - console has been setup
            lxc 20160415171849.553 INFO     lxc_utils - utils.c:mount_proc_if_needed:1726 - I am 1, /proc/self points to '1'
            lxc 20160415171849.556 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_rootfs_pivot_root:1050 - pivot_root syscall to '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lxc' successful
            lxc 20160415171849.557 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_tty:995 - 0 tty(s) has been setup
            lxc 20160415171849.561 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_personality:1393 - set personality to '0x8'
            lxc 20160415171849.561 DEBUG    lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_caps:2055 - drop capability 'mac_admin' (33)
            lxc 20160415171849.561 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:setup_caps:2058 - Operation not permitted - failed to remove mac_admin capability
            lxc 20160415171849.561 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_setup:3834 - failed to drop capabilities
            lxc 20160415171849.561 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:do_start:819 - failed to setup the container
            lxc 20160415171849.561 ERROR    lxc_sync - sync.c:__sync_wait:52 - An error occurred in another process (expected sequence number 2)
            lxc 20160415171849.562 WARN     lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_delete_network:2908 - failed to remove interface 11 'eth0'
            lxc 20160415171849.596 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1329 - failed to spawn 'elk01'
            lxc 20160415171849.598 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/share/lxcfs/lxc.reboot.hook' for container 'elk01', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160415171850.114 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/bin/lxd callhook /var/lib/lxd 9 stop' for container 'elk01', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160415171850.195 WARN     lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:172 - command get_cgroup failed to receive response
            lxc 20160415171907.873 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171907.873 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171907.907 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536
            lxc 20160415171907.907 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1498 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 165536 range 65536

odroid@odroid:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
odroid@odroid:~$ uname -a
Linux odroid 3.10.96-82 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 11 23:29:39 BRT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```